# Can't get tests to pass on Gitlab CI

Tags: activejdbc, activeweb

I've been trying to get our tests to pass on our Gitlab CI, but can't. I'm using the stock pipelines config that comes with Gitlab. All I've had to do is provide the gitlab yaml file to config the CI.

This is what we're using

```
image: maven:3.5.0-jdk-8-alpine

services:
  - postgres:latest

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: my_test_db
  POSTGRES_USER: my_test_user
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"
  ACTIVE_ENV: test

connect:
  image: postgres
  script:
  # official way to provide password to psql: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-envars.html
  - export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  - psql -h "postgres" -U "$POSTGRES_USER" -d "$POSTGRES_DB" -c "SELECT 'OK' AS status;"

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - "mvn -Denvironments=test -B db-migrator:migrate; mvn -Denvironments=test -DACTIVE_ENV=test -B test"
```

Everything works perfectly up to the point where the tests run. Then they all error out with similar messages:

```
383 [main] WARN org.javalite.activeweb.DBSpecHelper - no DB connections are configured, none opened
456 [main] WARN org.javalite.activeweb.DBSpecHelper - no DB connections are configured, none opened
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.528 sec <<< FAILURE! - in app.models.RoleTest
validatePresenceOfUsers(app.models.RoleTest)  Time elapsed: 0.071 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: Failed to retrieve metadata from DB, connection: 'default' is not available
```

I have one `database.properties` file that is checked in and is for tests only (our dev and prod envs use jndi). It looks like so:

```
test.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
test.username=my_test_user
test.password=
test.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres/edv_test
```

Again, migrations run using all this exact same config. I just can't figure out why the tests won't run. I understand why it's saying there's no default db, but I don't get why it's not seeing the test settings and configuring that connection as expected.

Comment: I suggest you run this code before your failure: `System.out.println(AppConfig.activeEnv())` -  this will tell you what value it is picking up as `ACTIVE_ENV`.

Comment: Ah, one step ahead of you. :) They won't format, but these are my debugs that prints out on the CI: `env: test` `load test env properties` The load test debug is in the block in my DbConfig: `if(Configuration.getEnv().equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
            System.out.println("load test env properties");
            loadConfiguration("src/main/resources/database.properties");
        } else {`

Comment: Not sure why you are loading properties file  your self

Comment: Well, we started not wanting to check in the database.properties due to the usual reasons. So my team and I have our own database-developer.properties set in gitignore that has our own local connection info. Because I could not get migrations to run on CI without a properties file, I decided to add just the CI test config to database.properties and that's why I'm using that check above.

Comment: did you know, you can have your connection file on the file system: http://javalite.io/database_connection_management#location-of-property-file

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But, then, that will be a hardcoded file that CI won't just see, but all devs will see and I'm guessing this will break local dev. I'm still just not sure why I can do migrations fine, but tests fail. I think what complicates all this is I have a few different ways I need to access a db connection: 1) the controllers in the app via a db connection filter, 2) async tasks that run on their own threads outside the controller db connection filter (via a command db connection), 3) dev and prod having different servers (jetty for dev, tomcat for prod), 4) and tests via mvn.

Comment: I've duplicated this locally as well. Setting `ACTIVE_ENV=test` and then running migrator works. Running `mvn test` fails with the same error I see above on CI. This whole line fails as well: `ACTIVE_ENV=test mvn test -Denvironments=test`. And, I can see in my output that DbConfig logs for my test env: `env: test`. There's a ton of mvn output when I use the `-X` switch and I'm slowly piling thru that. Maybe mvn test from the local dev machine just doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know, the Maven flag  `environments` like this: `mvn test -Denvironments=test` only works for the DB-Migrator, and not for the tests. Any JavaLite application in a standard running mode or as a test, it will be looking at `ACTIVE_ENV`. If this is not set, it will assume `development`. In test mode, it will be looking at `database.properties` block `development.test.xxx=yyy` as in http://javalite.io/database_configuration#property-file-configuration. 
Think of it as "development" environment, "test" mode.

Additionally, `DbConfig` is not involved in tests, as database connections in test have a special treatment (rollback transactions), see: http://javalite.io/testing_with_db_connection

Comment: This all makes sense. I am mostly sorted on the pieces here. I think our first fundamental problem is how to have a `database.properties` usable for a devs right now. And I suppose that answer is to use `ACTIVE_ENV` along with overrides for `database.properties`. I will start back at the beginning and re-work my way forward. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, most of the docs and use cases documented on the site address doing all this locally. And we've done this successfully. Where we're running into all our problems is on deployments. It's not a fault of the framework really, just us trying to make it work on staging and production environments. We're not using Jenkins - mostly Gitlab CI and now their Auto DevOps and I think for Javalite, this seems to be uncharted territory. We will continue to hack our way through it.

Comment: I think we need to do more documentation around deployment options. When you are done, would you mind contributing a page to the site that describes your setup: https://github.com/javalite/site-content? We will add ours too, around Jenkins, so that readers would have a choice.

Comment: Excellent! I will add to this for Gitlab once we get it working.

Comment: Appreciate, looking forward!